# How do i download files to the local downloads folder?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-download-manager

I enabled the download settings for files with WebView. I'm saving files with DownloadManager. But the files do not appear in the local downloads directory. The files I've downloaded are save here.

```
> file/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.myapp/files/x.mp3
```

I've tried a lot. But somehow it was not downloaded in the local downloads folder. What should I do?

> My Code

```
String string = String.valueOf((URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)));

            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);

            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setTitle("test17");
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getContext(), DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ,  string);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getActivity().getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: Use Prdownloader library .. it is easy to use and integrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#WriteExternalStorage) there are 2 types of external storage

> - Public files: Files that should be freely available to other apps and to the user. When the user uninstalls your app, these files should remain available to the user. For example, photos captured by your app or other downloaded files should be saved as public files.
> - Private files: Files that rightfully belong to your app and will be deleted when the user uninstalls your app. Although these files are technically accessible by the user and other apps because they are on the external storage, they don't provide value to the user outside of your app.

In your code, calling [DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) is equivalent to calling `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` which will get private file directory.

If you want to save downloaded files to Download directory, use [DownloadManager.Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request#setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

```
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "x.mp3");
// call allowScanningByMediaScanner() to allow media scanner to discover your file
request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. But this code didn't work for me either. When the download starts, the application is stopped. I am using this fragment in a fragment. Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper Can you post a log that show error when your application stopped?

Comment: I don't see the log cat because of a problem. When you add this code, the application stops while downloading. --> "                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ,  string);"    But it's okay when you use it. --> "                request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(getContext(), DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS ,  string);"

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper If you replaced your code with the code that I suggested but your application stopped then I don't know what happened since you said there was no log, are you sure about that? what tab did you use to find your log?

Comment: Please check I added a logcat.

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper Well, there is no error on the log that you posted, I assume that you already take care of permission and check external storage availability since you can save to private storage. Only thing I can think is that you downloaded successfully but you don't see the file. Did you call `allowScanningByMediaScanner()`?  Because if you don't the only way to see the file is to mount  your external storage to computer.

Comment: Let's not assume that. "I assume that you already take care of permission and check external storage availability since you can save to private storage." :D I gave permission with the manifest. But I did not get permission from the user. The weird side of the data is that it records the data without the permission of the folder with the package name. Many thanks for solving the problem.

Comment: @BeginnerDeveloper Apparently, since API 19, write and read permission on private external storage doesn't need permission, I shouldn't have assumed as you said XD

Answer (score 4):

For Android Q and prior Android Q (<= P) you need to copy file from your storage location to Download folder using ContentResolver, the file will appear in Download folder

```
            val file = File(filePath)
            val manager =
                (context.getSystemService(Activity.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {                 
                val resolver = context.contentResolver
                val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, file.name)
                    put(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf")
                    put(
                        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.RELATIVE_PATH,
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS
                    )
                }

                val uri = resolver.insert(
                    MediaStore.Downloads.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    contentValues
                )

                val fos = resolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
                val fin = FileInputStream(file)
                fin.copyTo(fos!!, 1024)
                fos.flush()
                fos.close()
                fin.close()
            } else {
                var destination =
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                        .toString() + "/" + file.name

                val uri = Uri.parse("file://$destination")
                val fos = context.contentResolver.openOutputStream(uri!!)
                val fin = FileInputStream(file)
                fin.copyTo(fos!!, 1024)
                fos.flush()
                fos.close()
                fin.close()
            }
```

After just show notification with "downloaded" file name that opens system "Downlod" view

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val name = "Some Channel"
            val descriptionText = "Default channel"
            val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            val channel = NotificationChannel(DEFAULT_CHANNEL, name, importance).apply {
                description = descriptionText
            }
            // Register the channel with the system
            val notificationManager: NotificationManager =
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }

            val intent = Intent()
            intent.action = DownloadManager.ACTION_VIEW_DOWNLOADS
            val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)

            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, DEFAULT_CHANNEL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.save_icon)
                .setContentTitle("123file")
                .setContentText("File succesfully exported")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                // Set the intent that will fire when the user taps the notification
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

            with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)) {
                // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
                notify(135, builder.build())
            }
```